# Start a react theme downloaded from the internet

Tags: reactjs

I downloaded [this](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-react#) react theme and I would like to run it, i tried with `npm start` inside the folder but I get a bunch of errors (image attached).
How can I run it?[image]

Comment: did you remember to run the `npm install` or `yarn` command before running the `npm start`? (I cannot view the image as it it blocked in my org)

Comment: check package.json in theme folder, maybe react-scripts is in dependecy and not installed correctly.
delete node_modules folder then try to run `npm install` again

Comment: Should I cd in the main folder it in the src folder?

Comment: you should cd in main folder that contain package.json file @sanna

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I had to run `npm install` and then `npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

i was also getting some errors so I tried `npm install --force` and then `npm start` and it worked